# Is there any code available of dockerfile regarding the base image of hyperledger fabric?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hyperledger-fabric

After looking in github repository of fabric, I can only find a dockerfile saying "FROM _DOCKER_BASE_" which i couldn't find documented.

Does anybody know what is 'docker base' and what does the containers do exactly in the deployment?

This is background detail of the question. I am creating a consensus mechanism in go language and I am concern about the docker image size with grpc and go installed in an image. So I have checked the hyperledger images which is less in size and I wanted to find out how is these implemented.

Initially I thought that containers are executing the transactions written in chaincode in golang. But I don't see container running go language setup so I am confused and looking for answer

Comment: This could be interpreted as too broad. Please [edit] to either ask about this detail of Dockerfile syntax or how to make a small image with Go.

Comment: I am only asking about details of docker file, not not about how to make small image with go. that's just background detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that the dockerfile that docker is going to use to construct your container needs an image to start "FROM".

On Dockerhub you can find images build for golang like:
https://hub.docker.com/_/golang?tab=description
There you have information not only about the image itself but how to use it.

So for example if you want to use that image you should pull it first:

```
docker pull golang
```

Then modify the fabric Dockerfile accordingly and then run the container with your preferred options.(Note that the code below is from fabric github and I don't know about details of the dockerfile, just and example)

```
#
# Copyright Greg Haskins All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
FROM DOCKER_BASE
COPY scripts /tmp/scripts
RUN cd /tmp/scripts && \
    common/init.sh && \
    docker/init.sh && \
    common/cleanup.sh && \
    rm -rf /tmp/scripts
```

And then build your container like:
(from inside where dockerfile is, you can do it from outside passing the folder where dockerfile and all the things related to your future container are)

```
docker build -t mygoolangimage .
```

And after its build if everything its ok, you will have a new image that you could run with:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name mygoolangcontainer mygoolangimage
```

Not knowing that a dockerfile in order to be built needs an image looks like that you need to read the basics from docker containers, maybe you could start at https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ and then build something easy.

I could put information here about how to start working with Docker but the main site has everything you need.

-----EDIT-----

The part "DOCKER_BASE" in the github https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage refers to a makefile that has the following part:

```
DOCKER_BASE_amd64=ubuntu:xenial
DOCKER_BASE_s390x=s390x/debian:stretch
DOCKER_BASE_ppc64le=ppc64le/ubuntu:xenial
DOCKER_BASE_armv7l=armv7/armhf-ubuntu

DOCKER_BASE=$(DOCKER_BASE_$(ARCH))
```

Comment: I know the use of "FROM" but the confusion is _DOCKER_BASE_. And can you please provide the link for given piece of code. Thanks.

Comment: The code that I paste comes from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage/blob/master/config/baseos/Dockerfile.in, there you can see on root level a make file that describes what is DOCKER_BASE, I'll edit my response